# Amazon EC2 instance running a Sonarqube server going into StatusCheckFailed state too often

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, sonarqube, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a problem with an EC2 instance where we run a Sonarqube server. Sonarqube is running in a Docker container.

I have set up a Cloudwatch alarm that gets triggered when my EC2 instance fails checks and restarts the EC2 instance but it only gets triggered about 1 hour after the problem appears. I can see in my monitoring solution that the Sonarqube server fails ping checks and the EC2 alarm goes off 1 hour later.

I suspect there might be a problem with the Docker container. In the container logs I can only see 2 warning messages as posted below

`2023.04.07 23:46:31 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.p.ExpiredSessionsCleaner] Purge of expired session tokens has removed 1 elements 2023.04.07 23:46:31 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.p.ExpiredSessionsCleaner] Purge of expired SAML message ids has removed 0 elements 2023.04.08 06:53:12 WARN  es[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] timer thread slept for [2.1m/126080ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms] 2023.04.08 07:00:08 WARN  es[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmGcMonitorService$1@4f...6, interval=1s}>`

I have so far been unable to resolve the cause of the problem. Any advice on how to debug this or any other type of help would be much appreciated.